# Where does "\N{SPECIAL CHARACTER}" in Python come from?

Tags: python, special-characters, string-literals

I came across some `urwid` [tutorial](http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html), which included an example with code such as this:

```
...
main = urwid.Padding(menu(u'Pythons', choices), left=2, right=2)
top = urwid.Overlay(main, urwid.SolidFill(u'\N{MEDIUM SHADE}'),
    align='center', width=('relative', 60),
    valign='middle', height=('relative', 60),
    min_width=20, min_height=9)
urwid.MainLoop(top, palette=[('reversed', 'standout', '')]).run()
```

That `u'\N{MEDIUM SHADE}'` string literal drove me nuts for almost the entire day until I found out it was included — as comments! — in files under `/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/`... But nowhere did I find any hint as to using such a notation. I browsed Python documentation and could find nothing.

Out of curiosity I ran in my python interpreter:

```
print(u'\N{LOWER ONE QUARTER BLOCK}')
```

and I got

```
▂
```

Where does that kind of black magic come from? I mean, where is it explained one can use that... notation (?) to print out special characters using their friendly names? Does Python hide any other surprises like this one?

Comment: Unicode characters have long names like that

Comment: See [**`unicodedata`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html), e.g. `print(unicodedata.lookup('MEDIUM SHADE')` gives ▒.

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks! It's now mentally bookmarked for life :-) .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Towards the end of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals:

> \N{name} - Character named *name* in the Unicode database

Comment: Oh dear... I feel even more embarassed! It seems I overlooked that part of Python documentation about string literals. Thanks a whole bunch.

Comment: @Nasha It was only [added in 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#id10), don't feel so bad.